# Why I can not call function in my laravel controller?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have page with link like this in my laravel project: http://127.0.0.1:8000/page/39
Then I try to make ajax function like this

```
$(window).dblclick(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'test',
      success: function(r){
        alert(r);
      }
    });
  });
```

my route is like this :

```
Route::get('test', ['uses'=>'MyController@test']);
```

my function in controller is like this :

```
public function test(){
   echo 1;
}
```

when I run my ajax function the output is not 1, but when I change my link page like this :
http://127.0.0.1:8000/page

output of ajax is 1, what is wrong? help me.

Comment: `url: 'test'` is a relative url so if you are at `page/39` you will call `page/39/page`. Try using `url: '/test'`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here:

```
url: 'test',
```

change it to:

```
url: '{{ url("/test") }}',
```

and try again.

**Explanation:** In laravel, the `url()` helper is used to generate arbitrary URLs for your application.

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/urls)

Answer (score 0):

Please change the path in js code to:

The problem is when you are on http://127.0.0.1:8000/page/39  the request is sent to http://127.0.0.1:8000/page/test and not http://127.0.0.1:8000/test

You should be using absolute path `/test` not `test`

```
$(window).dblclick(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/test', //changed
      success: function(r){
        alert(r);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: how if I have url like this : localhost:8888/project/page/5
how is url of ajax? and route of laravel?

Answer (score 0):

somethimes in ajax functions cannot use the laravel routes,
first you try to use this

```
url : "{{route('route_name')}}"
```

if it will not working you can use the `Ziggy` ,
this is so good and its easy to use,

link: https://github.com/tightenco/ziggy

Answer (score -1):

Try naming your route: `Route::get('/test',  ['as' => 'testroute', 'uses' => 'MyController@test' ]);`

Then in your js call the route this way:

```
url = "{{ route('testroute') }}";
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  success: function(r){
    alert(r);
  }
});
```